# using module in function, that's import's in amother module

Tags: python, import, scope

I'm checking the next code, and it does not working. Why?

```
FILE_1.py:
import time
import FILE_2.py
FILE_2.some_function()

FILE_2.py:
def some_function():
    print('start')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('end')
```

why I'm getting "time not defined" if FILE_2.py was imported and now inside FILE_1.py, that have module time

Comment: If you import a module, you get access to the public functions from that module. You don't get access to the imported module's imports. So a Python file that uses `time` functions should `import time`.

Answer (score 0):

The File Should look like this:

FILE_1.py:

```py
import FILE_2.py
FILE_2.some_function()
```

FILE_2.py:

```py
import time
def some_function():
    print('start')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('end')
```

Comment: I'm undestend it, but at this way I'm must import module "time" twice, if I want to use it in the FILE_2.py too.